# Downloading Folders to my Local via SSH

Tags: ssh

I am learning SSH as it seems there are no good SSH GUIs for Macs. I know how to make db dumps, cruise through the directories, etc, but the one last piece of the puzzle I need to learn is how to download folders/entire directories from the server and onto my local computer so I can then move them to another server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 169):

`scp -r user@host:/path/to/folder/ local-copy-of-folder`

If you have SSH keys set up, you can tab-complete remote files/folders.

Comment: It has to be case sensitive.

Comment: To access the with specific identity file `scp -i "mypemfile.pem" -r user@host:/path/to/folder/ local-copy-of-folder`

Comment: i  have connected using putty, `scp /var/www/html/* /`, now what is the location on my computer, i tried with C:\code, but it is not working with C:

Comment: simple and useful answer, thanks a lot

Answer (score 16):

you can scp - which will allow you to securely copy between hosts.

to learn more you can do man scp

Its located in /usr/bin on linux. SCP or secure copy  command copies files and directories from one computer to another in batch. (For interactive user interface you can use SFTP as "user545035" stated. It encrypts all communication between the two machines.

```
$ scp my file remote.example.com:newfile
$ scp -r mydir remote.example.com:
$ scp remote.example.com:myfile .
$ scp -r remote.example.com:mydir .
```

TO specify an alternate username on the remote system, use the username@host syntax:

```
$ scp myfile solidariti@remote.example.com :
```

Useful options:

**-p**: Duplicate all file attributes (permissions, timestamps) when copying.

**-r**: Recursively copy a directory and its contents.

**-v**: Produce verbose output, useful for debugging.

`SFTP (host|username@host) openssh-client` located in the `/usr/bin` directory.
The sftp program copies files interactively between two computers. (As opposed to scp, which copies files in batch.) The user interface is much like that of ftp.

```
$ sftp remote.example.com
password: ******
sftp> cd MyFiles
sftp> ls
README
...
sftp> get README
Fetching /home/solidariti/Myfiles/README to README
```

If you username is different from your local one, use the username@host argument:

```
$ sftp solidariti@remote.example.com
```

Hope this gets you on your way.

Answer (score 9):

It's just...

```
scp -r username@remote:/path/to/folder/ /dest/local/path
```

On Windows:

```
scp -r username@remote:/path/to/folder/  C:\\Users\\User\\\Documents
```

References:
[1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy
[2]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS

Answer (score 4):

I would look for an 'SFTP Client' and use that.  Maybe FileZilla

Answer (score 2):

[Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) was my favorite SSH/FTP/DAV GUI when I used a Mac. Looks like it's been updated to include Google Docs and S3 since then, too.

Answer (score 1):

if you have `pem` file you can use something like that

```
scp -i mypemfile.pem -r user@host:/path/to/folder/ local-copy-of-folder
```

Comment: If this is to be useful introduction to SCP then it needs more detail and explanation.